# Spin vector representation in an arbitrary direction $\hat{n}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-spin

Take a spin $1/2$ particle with its spin pointing along $\hat{n}$ defined by

$$\hat{n}=(\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta},\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta},\cos{\phi})$$

We are measuring the spin along $\hat{n}$ and the operator corresponding to this observable is $\vec{S}\cdot\hat{n}$.

$$\vec{S}\cdot\hat{n}=\frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{pmatrix} \cos{\phi} & \sin{\phi}e^{-i\theta} \\ \sin{\phi}e^{i\theta} & -\cos{\phi} \end{pmatrix}$$

Now my question is, since we cannot measure spin in all three dimensions simultaneously, then how can we define the dot product $\vec{S}\cdot\hat{n}$  $\\$ (which clearly shows the sum of spins in all three directions for a particular $\hat{n}$)?

Also since spin in any two directions can be represented in terms of spin up and spin down of the remaining direction, is it meaningful to write $\vec{S}\cdot\hat{n}$ for any arbitrary direction?

Comment: $\vec S\cdot\hat n$ is a single operator. It has two eigenvectors with eigenvalues $\pm\hbar/2$, which correspond to the two possible outcomes when the observable $\vec S\cdot\hat n$ is measured. Physically, these outcomes represent spin $\pm \hbar/2$ along the $\hat n$ direction. Measuring $\vec S\cdot\hat n$ does not require measuring $\vec S\cdot (1,0,0)$ or $\vec S\cdot (0,1,0)$ or $\vec S\cdot  (0,0,1)$. We cannot measure all three of those together, but we can measure the individual observable $\vec S\cdot \hat n$ for any individual direction $\hat n$.

Comment: I got it, thankyou @Chiral Anomaly

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is, since we cannot measure spin in all three dimensions simultaneously, then how can we define the dot product $S\cdot \hat{n}$  (which clearly shows the sum of spins in all three directions for a particular $\hat{n}$)?

The definition $S\cdot \hat{n}$ does not allow you to simultaneously measure the spin along different axes. You can check, starting from the expression of $S\cdot \hat{n}$ (for $x,y,z$ axes) that,
$$|\langle{\Psi^x_{\pm}}|\Psi^y_{\pm}\rangle|^2 = |\langle{\Psi^y_{\pm}}|\Psi^z_{\pm}\rangle|^2 = |\langle{\Psi^z_{\pm}}|\Psi^x_{\pm}\rangle|^2 = \frac{1}{2}$$

This shows that consecutive measurements are unaffected by previous results.

What is shown by,
$$S\cdot \hat{n} = \frac{\hbar}{2} (\vec{\sigma} \cdot \hat{n})$$

is simply that we expect the spin states in arbitrary directions to be part of the space spanned by the $\sigma_i$.

Comment: I have calculated its eigenstates and got $\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$ and $ \sin\frac{\theta}{2} e^{\iota\phi}$, but I am confused, to what spin state, these eigenvectors corresponds to? and how to compute the probability expression(which you told to calculate) from these states?